# Procedure to check for non-existing values in a foreign table oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

My requirement is to write a procedure to add values in COUNTRIES table. But, first it should check if corresponding values exist in another table, REGIONS as it is a foreign key. Only if the values exist is the insert into COUNTRIES table allowed. Otherwise, no.

I wrote a piece of code,but it is throwing a bunch of errors:

> ORA-00950 missing keyword PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol THEN when
>   expecting one of the following: (begin case declare and exception
>   exit) (a bind variable) (continue close current delete fetch lock)

I wrote this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addi1 (c_cntry_id IN OUT COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE,
                                       c_cntr_name IN COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE, 
                                       c_rgn_id IN COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE)
IS
l_exst number(1);

begin
  select case 
           when exists
(   select r.region_id from regions r where r.region_id  IN
(SELECT REGION_ID from regions)

                        );
           then 1
           else 0
         end  into l_exst


  if l_exst = 1 
  then
    INSERT INTO countries(COUNTRY_ID, COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_ID)
    values (c_cntry_id, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id);
  else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('YOU CANNOT'); 
  end if;
end;
/
```

Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong and how I can modify the query?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way to enforce a foreign key.  It does not work in a multi-user environment because we cannot see what other users are doing in their uncommitted sessions.  So maybe your code would find a REGION when some other user is about to commit a deletion, or contrariwise your code might fail to find a REGION while somebody else is about to commit an insertion.

Much better to leave it to Oracle's built-in features.

1. Define (and enable!) an actual foreign key constraint between REGION and COUNTRIES.
2. Just insert into the COUNTRIES table.
3. Handle the foreign key violations in an Exceptions block.

This solution uses the PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT to define a specific exception for the purpose.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99871).

```
create or replace procedure addi1 (c_cntry_id in out countries.country_id%type,
                                       c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                       c_rgn_id in countries.region_id%type)
is
    region_not_found exception;
    pragma exception_init(region_not_found, -2291);
begin
    insert into countries(country_id, country_name,region_id)
    values (c_cntry_id, c_cntr_name,c_rgn_id);
exception
    when region_not_found then
        dbms_output.put_line(c_rgn_id||' is not a valid REGION id'); 
        raise;
end addi1;
/
```

Note that it raises an exception; this means that the calling program knows the insert failed and so can make an informed choice about its next step.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is the syntax for checking the existence of a record.

```
create or replace procedure addi1 (c_cntry_id in out countries.country_id%type,
                                       c_cntr_name in countries.country_name%type, 
                                       c_rgn_id in countries.region_id%type)
is
    region_exists pls_integer;
begin
    begin
        select 1 into region_exists
        from regions r 
        where r.region_id = c_rgn_id;
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            region_exists := 0;
    end;
    if region_exists = 1 then
         ...
```

But as I said, don't do this.

---

> ",it gave me ORA-00001 "

So clearly you already have defined a COUNTRIES record with an ID of `'Ff'`.  If you want to handle the exception cleanly you can use the predefined DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception:

```
     when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
         dbms_output.put_line('There is an existing COUNTRIES record with an ID of' || c_cntry_id);
```

In real life we should always raise an exception: it's the calling program's prerogative to decide how serious the error is.  But feel free to suppress errors if you want.

Comment: thanks,I ran your first procedure and when I executed,it gave me ORA-00001 (unique key constraint).Now I don't want any ORA exceptions.Only those that I have defined (region_not_found exception). I am executing the procedure like this :DECLARE
   outputValue CHAR(2) := 'Ff';
begin
  addi1(outputValue,'JustKii',5);
end;
/

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your syntax question:

You always select FROM something. The from is missing in your query and there is a ; in the middle of it.

```
select case
             when exists (select r.region_id
                     from regions r
                    where r.region_id in (select region_id
                                            from regions)

                   ) then
              1
             else
              0
          end
     into l_exst
     from dual;
```

There is something odd with this part of the query:

```
select r.region_id
from regions r
where r.region_id in (select region_id
                      from regions)
```

Do you think the in part is necessary?

Comment: Yes,else,how will I know if the region_id exists in regions table?